# Angular 2 component tags breaks layout styles

Tags: css, angular

2 issues plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/uGSGtK6FtiICc1HbYy5i?p=preview

1. `margin-left` breaks
2. `flex-grow` breaks

and some other rules too due to components tags.

Styles provided by other team, they stored separately and some of them are related to `media-query`, so i can't use uglyhack with `:host { margin-left: auto; }`. Also some styles (`flex-grow` e.x.) have numerical values and can't be easily tracked and changed on real styles changes.

How this can be solved without writing angular-specific styles?

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left` doesn't not move `user` to the right. if you want it be there then use a style

```
.header-user {
   position: absolute;
   right: 16px;
   ...
}
```

`flex` layout works if you use a style on `<flex-item>` element. Yes, angular created this element inside the container that should be 1st child of the parent `div`.

Comment: 'margin-left doesn't not move user to the right' it does. just add `margin-left: auto` to `header-user` tag and this will work as expected. 'if you use a style on <flex-item> element' it cant be used so in many cases, styles should not be related to any framework

Comment: *'user' must be at right edge due to 'margin-left: auto', but 'header-user' tag breaks this*, indeed it was positioned to the left by default relative to the last item. it's already added in the header user, that should be removed. styles are not related to framework but related to html elements of the DOM.